# How to move an image/div from right to left continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'd like to do is animate a small image as well as a div (or an image within a div) from the right to the left of the screen, repeating once the image/div leaves the screen.

I found an example online that moves an image/div from left to right, but not all the way to the other side of the screen, and I am struggling to make it from right to left.

Here's what I have been doing

```
function moveTruck() {
        $("#ImageToMove").animate({
            "margin-right": "5000px"
        }, 3000, function () { $("#ImageToMove").css("margin-right", "10000"); moveTruck(); });
    }

    moveTruck();
```

Playing with the margin-right values. My CSS class is:

```
.HomeImageAnimate{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:80px;
    right:1000px;
}
```

Comment: make demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) for better explain what you trying to do .. cause we will ask you to provide html code to know what "#ImageToMove" is? .. so demo is better

Comment: It's worth noting that this same effect can be achieved with CSS transitions ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/anwo9ck3/)), and will be achievable even more easily with CSS animations once the spec becomes normative.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting , animating `left` property using values of `window.innerWidth` , container element width

```js
(function fx(el) {
  $(el).css("left", window.innerWidth)
    .animate({
      left: "-" + (window.innerWidth - $(el).width() * 2)
    }, 3000, "linear", function() {
      fx(this)
    })
}($("div")))
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
img {
  background: gold;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <img />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this truck div repeatedly goes from right to left.

HTML:

```
<div class="truck"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
   background: green;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.truck {
   margin-top:20px;
   width: 272px;
   height: 174px;
   cursor:pointer;
   position: absolute;
   margin-right: -150px;
   z-index: 3;
   background: red;
   border-radius:4px;
   width:200px;
   height:50px;     
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {   

    var moveTruck = function(){
        $(".truck").delay(2000).animate( {'right': '120%' }, 5000,'linear',function(){
            $(this).css({'right': '-50px'});
            moveTruck();
        });
    }
moveTruck();
})
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/JYmXYY)

Answer (score 0):

> function move(){
>
> ```
> width = $(window).width();
> objectWidth = $('#demo').width();
>
> margin = width + objectWidth + 'px';
> restart = -100 - objectWidth + 'px';
>
> $('#demo').animate({
>     'margin-left': margin
> }, 3000, function(){
>   $('#demo').css('margin-left', restart);
>     move();
> });
>  }
> ```
>
> move();

Try this out, it calculates the exact width of object and window - should always work no matter the screen size. You were trying to use an absolute pixel value, won't always work.

https://jsfiddle.net/w9pgmm9d/3/